# scp the latest file of a remote folder

Tags: scp

I know, the subject has been covered several times, but I anyhow can't make it work. 
I am a very unexperienced web developer. 
I created several jobs which : 
1) save the sql dump into a folder on the server
2) download the content of the folder on my locale machine. (SCP)

Problem is, the way I created the 2) job, all the files which are existing in 1) are transfered to my local machine. I am looking for a way to only scp the latest created file. I tried this possibility, that several person qualify as the best answer (`ls -t nlb* | head -1`) but anyhow get an error message.

Any chance someone could simply correct the command ? 
scp -i /users/myname/desktop/projects/online/mykey.pem ec2-user@XXXXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/dbbckp/`* | head -1` /users/myname/downloads/dbbckp

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use rsync which sync the gap only, or you can name your dump files in a proper way so you know which one to copy.